# string replace add in powershell

Tags: string, powershell

hello guys i'm a beginner in powershell , i have an outpout file from a script that i createdto check all volume data (datax) on a netapp SVM(na0maa-euc01)
level3 folder who have everyone permission on it and without active directory security groups(must positionned on the level3 folders) , so the outpout txt file  is like that

```
\\na0maa-euc01\data1\Nissan Production Engineering\TC Facility\X11M 
\\na0maa-euc01\data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry\IQMS\Data
\\na0maa-euc01\data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry\PROJECT INFORMATION\Data
\\na0maa-euc01\data2\powertrain_emb_ice_algorithm_OLD\Data\05_DCM
```

those level 3 folder where copied from a 7 mode netapp named f-typhon-old were the acl are ok

```
\\f-typhon-old\data1\Nissan Production Engineering.mig\TC Facility\X11M
\\f-typhon-old\data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry.mig\IQMS\Data
\\f-typhon-old\data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry.mig\PROJECT INFORMATION\Data
\\f-typhon-old\data2\powertrain_emb_ice_algorithm_OLD.mig\Data\05_DCM
```

so i created a new file with a baseline to correct the acl like that

```
data1\Nissan Production Engineering\TC Facility\X11M
data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry\IQMS\Data
data1\Powertrain_DIP-A entry\PROJECT INFORMATION\Data
data2\powertrain_emb_ice_algorithm_OLD.mig\Data\05_DCM
```

made a little script with a loop on the file  with get-acl and set-acl to correct but the issue is i need a text manipulation to create a variable $level3old to store in it the path with .mig in the level1 folders i don't now how to do it or if it was possible in powershell

```
$Pth = "C:\temp\mig\mig_CDOT\0INCHE\Log\Robocopy\Extract\acl_user"
$filerd = "na0maa-euc01"
$filers = "f-typhon-old"
$N3 = gc $pth\N3_witheveryoneacess_base.txt

foreach ($level3 in $N3) {
    $level3old = how too replace datax\level1\level2\level3 with datax\level1.mig\level2\level3
    get-acl "\\$filers\$level3old " | set-acl "\\$filerd\$level3"
}
```

Comment: `$level3old = $level3 -replace '^\\\\.*?\\(.*?\\[^\\]+)','$1.mig'` will replace the system name and add the `.mig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what your variables contain at all times. So I will provide some examples.

**Assuming `$level3` contains the server name and no `.mig`**

```
$level3 = '\\na0maa-euc01\data1\Nissan Production Engineering\TC Facility\X11M'
$level3old = $level3 -replace '^\\\\.*?\\(.*?\\[^\\]+)','$1.mig'

# Output
$level3old
data1\Nissan Production Engineering.mig\TC Facility\X11M
```

**Assuming `$level3` starts with the shared folder and contains no `.mig`**

```
$level3 = 'data1\Nissan Production Engineering\TC Facility\X11M'
$level3old = $level3 -replace '^.*?\\[^\\]+','$&.mig'

# Output
$level3old
data1\Nissan Production Engineering.mig\TC Facility\X11M
```

**Explanation:**

`-replace` uses regex matching followed by a string replace (with some match references). Since `\` is a regex special character, it has to be backslash escaped for a literal match. So to match `\`, you need `\\`. To match `\\`, you need `\\\\`, i.e. one `\` escape for each literal `\`.

The initial `^` matches the beginning of the string. It is the first possible place to start matching a string.

`.*?` lazily matches any characters. This usually continues matching until it hits another matching condition. So `.*?\\` will match any character up until and including the next `\`.

`[^]` is the negation character class. Anything following the `^` within the `[]` means match anything except those characters. `[^\\]` matches anything except `\`.

`+` matches one or more of the previous match. `[^\\]+` matches anything except `\` one or more times.

In the replacement string, `$1` refers to the matched characters in capture group 1. In the regex portion, `()` denotes a capture group. The first open `(` begins capture group, which is given the name 1 unless you explicitly name it.

In the replacement string, `$&` refers to every matched character. `$0` could also be used because an entire match defaults to capture group 0.